# Strong Convergence of Fredholm Operators, as used in Callias' proof of his index theorem

Tags: operator-theory, strong-convergence

In his paper *Axial Anomalies and Index Theorems on Open Spaces*, Callias provides a wonderful index theorem
$$\mathrm{index}(L)=\lim_{z\to0} \mathrm{Tr}B_z\quad\text{where}
\quad B_z=\frac{z}{L^\dagger L+z}-\frac{z}{LL^\dagger+z}$$
for $L:D\to H$ a closed Fredholm operator on a dense subset $D$ of the Hilbert space $H$ and $z\in\mathbb C$.

The proof assumes that $B_z$ is trace-class on $H$, and that $Tr |B_z|$ is bounded for $z$ in some domain $C\in\mathbb C$ with $0\in \overline C$. It considers the expression
$$ \widetilde B_z=\frac{z}{L^\dagger L+z}-Pr_{\mathrm{Ker}(L^\dagger L)}-\frac{z}{LL^\dagger+z}+Pr_{\mathrm{Ker}(LL^\dagger)}$$
where $Pr_S$ denote the projection operator on the linear subspace $S$ of $H$. The author then asserts without comment that $\lim_{z\to0} \widetilde B_z=0$ strongly, from which the index theorem follows in a straightforward manner.

How would one go about proving that $ \widetilde B_z$ indeed converges strongly to the zero operator as $z$ approaches zero?